# NMaximize -- Error + Output

Tags: mathematical-optimization

When I run the code,

```
Table[
  NMaximize[
    {f[α, χ, τ], 0 <= α <= 2 π, 0 <= χ <= π}, {α, χ}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 10
  ],
  {τ, 0.1, 2, 0.1}
]
```

I get the output but with it I also get errors. Please see the attached picture.

[image: screenshot of errors]

What do the errors mean? Can the output be trusted with the errors?

P.S: I have omitted the lengthy code preceding the aforementioned code to maintain brevity. I can provide it on request.

Comment: "Can the output be trusted with the errors?" - anything with the words "failed to converge" is supposed to make you suspicious.

Comment: @J.M. The thing is, I have graphs for this function previously and I expect the results to be qualitatively the same as I am getting. Better question: how do I rectify the error?

Comment: Then you can use your graphs to check: see if the purported extrema are located at where your contour/density plots say they are.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, most of the results check out. But then again as you said, anything with the words "failed to converge" is supposed to make you suspicious. How do I rectify the error before proceeding to be sure I am not making any mistake?

Comment: why are you specially requesting a low working precision?   ( If you want ot work at high precision you should make your table exact , `1/10,2,1/10` )